# Upvoting a comment doesn't update the UI

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, ios-app, comment-voting

When you upvote a comment in the latest beta release of the iOS app, it doesn't update the vote count and coloring.

Instead it flashes and returns to its normal color. When refreshing, the UI shows the correct vote count on the comment.

(Version 1.3.1.209 on iOS 8.3)

Comment: Yeah I noticed this last night. Then thought it didn't stick so I hit upvote again and it said I can't upvote a second time.

Comment: Indeed. The error is weird too. You can't "mark" a comment twice. I would say "upvote".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, I overhauled comment updating to fix a crash and broke the upvote UI. Basically I told it to update from its original state to its original state.  It'll be fixed in the next build.

Comment: BAM! that was fast

Comment: @mhlester I had already submitted to the app store so I freaked out when I saw it.

Comment: Yikes! Guess it really could have made a difference to have posted this last night when I noticed it

Comment: How can I get you to switch over to the android app team? ;)

Comment: Looks like somebody misses his iOS app :)

Comment: Build is out now. @ShadowWizard I did make one small commit to Android 2 weeks ago so you never know. ;)

Comment: *Looking around to make sure we are alone* - if you can sneak a confirmation dialog for comment deletion in android app it would be great! :-D

Comment: It works now @Brian. Thanks.